# EF incorrectly maps ID property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two EF models where one derives from the other.

```
public class Party
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Key { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Party
{

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

When I put in the properties in a **EDIT** view using hidden fields like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Key)
```

both fields get the same value, and I get a validation error since the ID property cannot be a GUID.

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-range="Feltet ID må være mellom 1 og 2147483647." data-val-range-max="2147483647" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="Feltet ID er obligatorisk." id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="3b9ba191-3a3c-47d9-8bb7-48cc552cc6ec" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Feltet Key er obligatorisk." id="Key" name="Key" type="hidden" value="3b9ba191-3a3c-47d9-8bb7-48cc552cc6ec" />
```

How can I tell EF that the property called ID is **NOT** the primary key (since I presume EF assumes this)?

Comment: Is this because of the controller url? my route setup is {controller}/{action}/{id} and the url for my edit action is: http://localhost:54907/Customer/Edit/3b9ba191-3a3c-47d9-8bb7-48cc552cc6ec

Comment: If I rename the ID property to e.g CustomerID and apply the Column attribute to preserve database structure I can confirm that the field no longer equals the Key property. My question stands however, on how I can keep my ID property without it being set to the id part of the url.

Comment: Can you please show the code that you use for the DbContext and how you are mapping the discriminator ??? And also which version of EntityFramework are you using ...

Answer (score 0):

Since any domain model has to have an ID in EF just create another property in your customer class and decorate it with [Key]

```
public class Customer : Party
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomID { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No, I don't think that is correct since Party has a key property. I think the problem is the ID property being assigned the value from the url string.

Comment: Ok then what is your database schema ? Do you have one table for customer and one for party ? What are the primary keys in the database ?

Comment: Both the party class and the customer class is stored in the same table = Party having a column called Discriminator telling the EF which type each record is. The primary key as my model shows above = Key.